# Changing justified caption in beamer within document

Tags: beamer, captions

For having justified figure captions in my presentation, I'm using the `caption` package.

I would like to change the prefix of figures within a beamer presentation from "Figure" to "Supplementary Figure", I tried the following options (separately), but none of them had a success:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplementary Figure}  % no effect
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\center\thefigure\insertcaption\par}  % no effect
\captionsetup[figure]{name=S}  % no effect
```

I would be greatful for any hint on whether this is possible with the `caption` package or maybe even with a pure solution in beamer (I just hadn't found a way to justify captions in beamer).

By using the following minimal working example, I could further pin down the problem: Calling `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}` only affects the caption on the same slide and unexpectedly not the captions on the following ones.

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide 1}
\begin{figure}
% \includegraphics{} here
\caption{First Test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide 2}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}  % only works on same slide
\begin{figure}
% \includegraphics{} here
\caption{Second Test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide 3}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Third Test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An obvious fix would be to call `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}` outside of the slide, but I'm using `\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}`.

Is there nonetheless a more elegant way than calling `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}` on every slide?

Comment: Please add a small but compilable test document. If I guess enough code to test, then `\renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplementary Figure}` works just fine for me

Comment: Thanks for insisting on a minimal example, which helped me to pin down the problem a bit closer: `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}` only affects one slide in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each frame is a group. If you want to make changes which affect all further frames, you should make them outside of the frame environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide 1}
\begin{figure}
% \includegraphics{} here
\caption{First Test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}  % only works on same slide

\begin{frame}{Slide 2}

\begin{figure}
% \includegraphics{} here
\caption{Second Test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide 3}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Third Test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Personally, I would add such changes to the appendix

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\apptocmd{\appendix}{
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}  % only works on same slide
}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide 1}
\begin{figure}
% \includegraphics{} here
\caption{First Test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\appendix

\begin{frame}{Slide 2}

\begin{figure}
% \includegraphics{} here
\caption{Second Test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide 3}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Third Test}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this already comes very close to a possible solution. I'm using `\documentclasse[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}`, which is why I renewed the figure caption inside a frame.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki You can patch the appendix

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki Also, it is frowned upon to edit your question in a way which invalidates existing answers. In the future, please ask a new question in such cases.

Comment: This works, thanks for the solution. Sorry for the edit, I get the point.